# Will a bite from another cat turn into an abscess?

Tags: cats, injury, infections

I have two housecats. They occasionally chase each other and play a bit rough.

Today I found a bite mark on one of my cat's necks. It's dry and red, I'm guessing a day or so old now.

How likely is it that this will develop into an abscess? I'm assuming that because they live together and stay indoors, the risk is pretty low.

Comment: related https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/26652/what-happens-if-bite-wound-abscesses-in-cats-left-untreated but not a duplicate as i see it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very often cats get abcesses from wounds caused by bites and claws so you will have to keep an eye on any wounds your cat get.

The cause for many abcesses is that the wounds are deep and you will not be able to see how deep they are.

wounds caused by cat claws and teeth will often start to heal from the outside of the wound ,the skin heals first and this blocks bacteria inside the wound causing an infection under the skin.

The cats beeing indoors does not reduce the risk for infection in any significant way.

Comment: I took my cat to the vet, turns out there was no abscess and the wound was healing just fine. Thanks for the advice :)